# how to handle a decorator that doesn't exist

Tags: python, exception, decorator

I'd like to import jit for speeding up my code, but how do I handle an error in numba is not installed on some computers? Say in the code below:

```
from numba import jit

@jit
def some_function(x):
    ....#some more code
```

now, `some_function` would run fine even without the decorator applied but just a bit slower. So I could put a try and except as:

```
try:
    from numba import jit
except:
   pass
```

but how do I handle this part of the code?

@jit <-----
def some_function(x):
    ....#some more code

I could possibly maybe make something like two functions:

```
try:
    @jit <----
    def some_function(x):
    ...
except:
    def some_function(x):
    ...
```

even if this would work, it seems not good to duplicate the code.So, what is the solution to this? How do I make the decorator sort of disappear/not work if there's an import error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just `return` the `function` itself like,

```
try:
    from numba import jit
except ImportError as err:
    jit = lambda x: x # return the function itself
```

Comment: this is exactly what I need.